# Haskell 'scanl with recursion' memory issue

Tags: haskell, recursion, out-of-memory

I would like to do the following:

```
[2,4,3,7,9,3]
[2,6,9,6,5,8]
[2,8,7,3,8,6]
[2,0,7,0,8,4]
```

I.e. in each phase I would like to modularly (10 in this case) sum up all the values from the beginning of the list to the current position, creating a new list: `` [2, (2+4) `mod` 10, (2+4+3) `mod` 10, (2+4+3+7) `mod` 10...] ``, and I would like to call this multiple times.

My code is:

```hs
applyMulti :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
applyMulti 0 dat = dat
applyMulti n dat = applyMulti (n - 1) $ apply dat

apply :: [Int] -> [Int]
apply dat = scanl1 (\a x -> (a + x) `mod` 10) dat
```

That works fine with small of data and small repetition count. But with a list of 500k Ints running 100 times, it eats up the memory and the program is killed. I don't understand, why. Even `500k * 100` should not be huge, but that could even be optimized by the compiler.

I also tried a non-tail-recursive version:

```hs
applyMulti n dat = apply . applyMulti (n - 1) $ dat
```

and I even used:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, StrictData, Strict #-}
```

What is my mistake and how should I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you *change* anything after adding BangPatterns? It won't do anything by itself, you need to use some bang patterns.

Comment: Can not reproduce: `applyMulti 100 [1 .. 500000]` seems to work fine.

Comment: It can of course be further optimized, especially the `\a x -> (a+x) `mod` 10` part, where does the (500k length) list originates from, that might be the problem.

Comment: @amalloy, the BangPatterns has no sense in this case any more, because I also added the two "strict" features.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike, How would you optimize that? Actually, I use `((\`mod\` 10) .) . (+)` in my code, but I did not want to copy that. And even not sure if it optimizes it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce. The memory perhaps increases 200 megabytes, and that includes the `ghci` runtime itself.

We can work with a *strict* version of `scanl` however to improve memory usage: [**`scanl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl-39-)  which will force evaluating the list items as `scanl` enumerates over it:

```
import Data.List(scanl')

apply :: [Int] -> [Int]
apply [] = []
apply (d:ds) = scanl' (\a x -> (a + x) `mod` 10) d ds
```

Comment: Thanks, scanl' worked. I don't really understand why is that difference, because I used strict evaluation, and I understand that scan1 did not, but a single run of the apply function run smoothly even with larger amount of data. Anyways, I have now a solution :)